# Where Does the Ubuntu "System Ready" Drum Roll Come From?

Tags: sound-theme

Was it sampled from a song?  Was it created as original content for the operating system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sound is composed by **Nathaniel McCallum**, according to the copyright file included in its package. Most likely, it is original content.

```
$ head -n 6 /usr/share/doc/ubuntu-sounds/copyright
This is Ubuntu's GNOME audio theme.

Copyright (C) 2004 Canonical Ltd. <http://www.canonical.com>
Sounds composed and recorded by Nathaniel McCallum <npmccallum@canonical.com>

This work is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License.
```

For users who are unaware, the "system ready" drum roll refers to the sound played when the user has reached the login screen. The sound length is 1 second.

The sound is available as `system-ready.ogg` file that is included in the [`ubuntu-sounds`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ubuntu-sounds) package, or can be found at full path on your system as below.

```
/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/system-ready.ogg
```

The package is installed by default in Ubuntu releases only.